# Bug scroll horizontal

Tags: html, css, html5, programación-móvil

Cambiar de lugar  la herramienta de inspeccionar los elementos del codigo del navegador cambia algo en la maquetacion del codigo o como se vea responsivamente? resulta que lo tenia puesto en el lado derecho como varios, y luego lo cambie para abajo por un bug que generaba el scroll horizontal, resulta que lo volvi a poner como lo tenia antes (a la derecha) y ahora todo el codigo me genera scroll horizontal, tiene algo de sentido esto?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

esa herramienta siempre se bugea, me pasa todos los días, que parece que no estuviera tomando los estilos pero es error del navegador. cuando pase eso puedes probar a desactivar y activar la opcion Toogle device toolbar (el botón que tiene un teléfono y un tablet), o cerrar el navegador y volver a abrirlo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Es posible que tus llamadas a medios no esten correctamente dispuetas.
Por ejemplo:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Asegúrate de que los estilos implicados estás correctamente adaptados a cada uno de los distintos tamaños de dispositivo para garantizar la responsividad de los mismos.

Revisa la documentación y tu código.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: He corregido la respuesta